# How TCP KeepAlive packets trigger and transmitted

Tags: aws-nlb, tcp-keepalive

How does TCP KeepAlive packets gets generated from Windows Core 2019?  What are the subscribers or listeners or the message?

It is clear Windows OS has KeepAlive registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ that custom values can added or updated for the following.

KeepAliveTime: 30000
KeepAliveInterval: 1000
TcpMaxDataRetransmissions: 10

After the change and rebooting the Win OS. I turned on WireShark capture and expected the OS to emit TCP KeepAlive messages every 30 seconds, however, I do not see anything.

How does TCP KeepAlive packets gets generated from Windows Core 2019 (or in general Windows OS)?  What are the subscribers or listeners of the message? How can I find out the OS generated TCP KeepAlive messages?